# How to report an Ubuntu bug without using apport

Tags: bug-reporting

Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, 64 bit, kernel 3.2.0-58

I used to be able to report a bug to Ubuntu by simply double clicking on the .crash files in directory /var/crash. Last week I changed internet service providers. Since then, when I double click a .crash file, the upload proceeds until the progress bar is almost to the right edge, the network traffic shows the size of the .crash file has been uploaded, and then a dialog appears with title "Network problem" and message:

"Cannot connect to crash database, please check your Internet connection.
  HTTP Error 502: Bad Gateway"

I am using my new internet service provider for all other purposes without problem. From what I have read, this particular error indicates a problem that is not in my control.

I would like to continue to report bugs to Ubuntu. Is there a way to do so with out using apport so as to circumvent the 502 network error? For example, can I copy the .crash file to DropBox, and submit it to Ubuntu?

Comment: Press Alt+F2 and run `ubuntu-bug <package-name>`.